# jquery drag image and calculate the dragging space

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

Guys now I made a small image uploader to upload image and and see the image before upload it to the server  using JQuery and it work well with me
it's some thing like this example http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

but I want the user to drage the image to select the part he want to crop 
it mean I want to calculate the dragged space from left and top
so what is the best way in JQuery to calculate this space ??

note : I'm using  this method

```
$("#upload-preview img").draggable();
```

Comment: So you have an assignment and you don't want to stress yourself with comming up with a solution? Clearly you put in zero effort into doing this yourself so far. At least with what's visible here so far

Comment: HI Andreas, this is not assignment and I'm really typed my code from scratch and tried more and more to search to find any method in Jquery to make me calculate the dragged space but not find any thing ..... any way thanks for your help

Comment: I can't understand what you expect from that dragged space. You have an old position and a new. You do a subtraction. That's all there is to it?

Comment: Andreas , I don't know to take the old position value and the new position value by Jquery ..... 
but know i found the best way to do that ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

we can use the `offset.left`  and `offset.top`  to get the positions values such as

```
$('#dragThis').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });
```